# How to select content from an iframe after loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I've made a Chrome Extension that loads my New Tab page with an `<iframe>` of my YouTube subscription page (I got around the `SAMEORIGIN` issue) and want to copy an element of the document into another `<div>`, the `#content` element to be precise. Here's my code:

**Background.html**

```
<html> 
    <head>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="window.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="left"  name="left"></iframe>
        <div id="canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Window.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $left = $('#left');

    $left.attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions');

    var $leftDoc = $left.contentWindow.document;
    $leftDoc.querySelector('#content').clone().appendTo('#canvas');
});
```

**Script.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(info) {
        var headers = info.responseHeaders;
        for (var i = headers.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            var header = headers[i].name.toLowerCase();
            if (header == 'x-frame-options' || header == 'frame-options') {
                headers.splice(i, 1); // Remove header
            }
        }
        return {
            responseHeaders: headers
        };
    }, {
        urls: ['*://*/*'], // Pattern to match all http(s) pages
        types: ['sub_frame']
    }, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

As it is right now, YouTube loads, but I can't get a hold of the document in the `<iframe>`, as it's calling the property as `undefined`. I'm trying to get that `div#content` to load without anything else for ease of navigation from my new tab page. Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT:** `#content` is the `div` that displays your subscription feed, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using native methods like `contentWindow` on a jQuery object, and not waiting for the Iframe to load, what you want is more

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $left = $('#left');

    $left.on('load', function() {
        $(this).contents().find('#content').clone().appendTo('#canvas');
    });

    $left.attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions');
});
```

Comment: Great, that works! I have a follow up question. I'm not getting an error along the lines of a `SAMEORIGIN` issue. Should I add another listener to invoke `script.js` again when that happens? The full error is: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-extension://XYZ" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "chrome-extension", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.`

Comment: Not quite sure, but script.js adds an event listener, and I think that fires every time headers are received, and would sidestep the same-origin policy for every request? If you get the same-origin error when changing the source of the iframe etc. you probably have to change the headers again, I think. Again, I've never had to bypass the Same-origin policy in an extension, so not sure how that works.